# ApiGen on windows.Can't able to run apigen command

Tags: php, windows, apigen

Can anybody tell how to get working APIGen on windows. I have installed ApiGen using PEAR and the file of ApiGen resides in

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13

there are two types of file here one with batch extension and other with file extension both having  name apigen.

I am getting below error while using apigen command.

```
Warning: require(Texy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen on line 48

Call Stack:
    0.0015     792712   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
    0.0141    1646736   2. class_exists() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:64
    0.0142    1647048   3. ApiGen\{closure}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Texy.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear') in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen on line 48

Call Stack:
    0.0015     792712   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
    0.0141    1646736   2. class_exists() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:64
    0.0142    1647048   3. ApiGen\{closure}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0

PHP Warning:  require(Texy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen on line 48
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
PHP   2. class_exists() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:64
PHP   3. ApiGen\{closure}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Texy.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear') in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen on line 48
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
PHP   2. class_exists() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:64
PHP   3. ApiGen\{closure}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\apigen:0
```

Answer (score 6):

Please follow these step (refer from this page https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen/wiki/installation-on-windows)

- Install apigen.phar in directory you want. For example: **C:\PHPCLI**
- Add **C:\PHPCLI** to Windows **Path**

  - In case that you or anyone don't know how to add Path in Windows. Right click on **My Computer** icon on desktop or start menu and click on **Properties**.
  - On left side of Windows properties page, click on **Advanced system settings**.
  - Click **Environment Variables...**
  - You can add **C:\PHPCLI** to **Path** in user variables or system variables. Choose one.
  - Click OK to all.
- Open command line and enter `cd C:\PHPCLI`
- Enter in command line again: `echo @php "%~dp0apigen.phar" %*>apigen.bat`
- Close command line and open new command line. Test by enter this command `apigen --help`
- It should display **ApiGen** help message.